# Cannot create fifo "[Errno 17] File Exists"

Tags: shell

I see output like:

```
ERROR:duckietown_challenges:evaluation: weird exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zuper_nodes_wrapper/wrapper_outside.py", line 62, in __init__
    os.mkfifo(fnin)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duckietown_experiment_manager/experiment_manager.py", line 34, in wrap
    asyncio.run(main(cie, logdir, attempts), debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/duckietown_experiment_manager/code.py", line 211, in main
    sim_ci = ComponentInterface(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zuper_nodes_wrapper/wrapper_outside.py", line 65, in __init__
    raise Exception(msg) from e
Exception: Cannot create fifo /fifos/simulator-in
```

This is running inside of a container so I'm not sure why or how I can control the existence or absence of this file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the volume, for example with

```
docker system prune --volumes
```